# Never have I had seen such a beautiful lady ( is it correct? )

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is it correct to say :

**Never have I had seen such a beautiful lady**

and what's the difference between this latter and this one :

**I have never had seen such a beautiful lady**

Comment: Neither sentence is correct English. You may find our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) better suited to you needs if you are learning English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is actually correct. You've got an extra element in there. It's either:

> ***Never had I seen such a beautiful lady.***

In the above example, **had** places the situation in the past.

Or:

> ***Never have I seen such a beautiful lady.***

In the above example, **have** places the situation in the present.

So it's either **have** *or* **had**--not both. Beyond that, there is no difference essentially between ***I have never*** and ***Never have I***.